# Is there a multiple equality function built in?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have 3 scalar values and I want to check if they are equal. For example 3 columns in a table. I work primarily in MS SQL

a = b and b = c

I can use this in a WHERE clause or a CASE statement. But is there a function built in such as:

EQUALS(a,b,c) <--this would evaluate to True / False

If not, is it possible in SQL to create a UDF that takes "2 or more" parameters, so I can create my own UDF that checks for equality?

Comment: No, there is not a built in function, and user defined functions must have strict parameters defined so you cannot create a function that accepts 2 + *n* parameters.

Comment: A UDF is poor idea, will ruin optimization.

Comment: No and no, in that order. UDFs are terribly limited and don't support variable arguments, neither in type nor in number. Various tricky expressions suggest themselves that you could use instead of `A = B AND B = C`, but they're almost certainly not worth it. In Azure SQL (and only there!) you could write `GREATEST(a, b, c) = LEAST(a, b, c)`, for example, but as this repeats the three values that seems silly.

Comment: Really bad idea, as others have suggested, but possible depending on where `a`, `b`, and `c` come from: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c42c34c367f799dbfce02af93cb1ba7

Comment: Another (slightly) dumb idea: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a INTERSECT SELECT b INTERSECT SELECT c)`. Neat, but integrating this sort of expression is likely to yield terrible execution plans since it typically can't effectively use indexes. (On the plus side, this considers `NULL` values equal without circuitous testing, which is useful in some circumstances.)

Comment: Just be aware that unlike a standard comparison, [that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71314383/is-there-a-multiple-equality-function-built-in#comment126055703_71314383) will return `true` if one or two of the values are `null`, because they're eliminated by the aggregate.

Comment: @SOS if NULLs are possible, you could circumvent that [with a simple COALESCE to a value not possible](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36ae1ac98e181829b06707079bdda5fc), but we don't know where the values are coming from and I already said the function was a dumb idea. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Hehe, yep. Just mentioning it because I had the exact same idea and found out when I tested it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to it might be the [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/all-transact-sql) operator.
Since it can be used with a select from values.

Although it's hardly worth it for only 3 columns.

Simplified example:

> ```
> create table test (
>  a int, 
>  b int, 
>  c int
> );
>
> insert into test (a, b, c) values
>   (1,1,1)
> , (1,1,2)
> , (2,2,2)
> , (2,3,4)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM test
> WHERE a = ALL(select v from (values (b),(c)) q(v))
> ```

> | a | b | c |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a81bb73717a05c188b73b2797d594c4e)*